# NameError: name 'myname' is not defined in Python

Tags: python, object

I'm getting this error quite often so I'd like to give an example:

```
class Me():
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name=name

def call():
  myname=Me("Alex")
  printIt()

def printIt():
  print(myname.name)

call()
```

Why am I getting this error instead of printing "Alex"? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myname` is a local variable that can only be used inside function where it's defined.

try pass it as argument:

```
def call():
    myname = Me("Alex")
    printIt(myname)

def printIt(myname):
    print(myname.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable defined in blocks has block-scope, which means they are not visible from outside. `myname` is in function `call`, and is only visible in `call`.
If we follow your style

```
myname = None

def call():
  global myname      
  myname = Me("Alex")
  printIt()

def printIt():       # now we could access myname 
  print(myname.name)
```

However, a better choice is to avoid unnecessary globals by using

```
def call():     
  myname = Me("Alex")
  printIt(myname)

def printIt(somebody):       # now we could access aPerson as well 
  print(somebody.name)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I understand it now. Specially this one works perfectly considering my style.

Answer (score 0):

myname is not a global  variable.  it is not in scope in the printIt method. it is local to the call method. if you want access to it, declare it in a way that it is global or pass the myname object as a parameter to printIt.